# Would Patronum be an appropriate name for a Classical Christian School Kickstarter platform?

Tags: translation-check

I am a web application developer. I am working on a platform similar to Kickstarter or GoFundMe to support individuals or teams who want to start or transition to a Classical Christian School. I see these individuals as advocates for this philosophy of education.

I have considered Suasoria, but the domain is taken. Would Suasori work? I am also considering Patronum.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What do you want the name to mean? Or is the meaning irrelevant as long as it's grammatical?

Comment: Thanks for asking. That's a good question. I've considered either "patron", as in someone who financially gives to a cause, or "advocate", someone who promotes or defends an idea.

Answer (score 1):

*Suāsōria* means "intended to persuade", as an adjective, or "a speech intended to persuade", as a noun.

*Suāsor* is a noun meaning "someone who persuades or advises"; *suāsōrī* is the dative singular, meaning "to/for someone who persuades".

*Pātrōnus* is a noun meaning "defender" or "patron"; *pātrōnum* is the accusative singular, used as the direct object of a verb. It can also mean "advocate" in a legal context.

I'm not aware of any specifically Christian context for *suāsor* or *suāsōria*, but *pātrōnum* (as I imagine you're aware) shows up in the Diēs Īrae:

> Quid sum, miser, tunc dictūrus?
> Quem **pātrōnum** rogātūrus?
> Cum vix justus sit secūrus?
>
> *[When the day of judgement comes…]*
> *What is this poor wretch then supposed to say?*
> *What **advocate** should I call upon,*
> *when even the righteous can scarcely be sure [of salvation]?*

The form here is *pātrōnum* instead of *pātrōnus* because it's the object of the verb "call upon" (*rogō*), indicating the person who is being called.

In this case, I would recommend *pātrōnus* instead of *pātrōnum*, since it's in the nominative or "default" case. But that's liable to be taken too.

Might I suggest ***pātrōcinium*** or ***pātrōcinia***? This is an abstract noun formed from *pātrōnus*, changing the meaning from "advocate" to "advocacy" or "protection". (The former is singular, the latter is plural, but that distinction doesn't matter too much with this word.)

P.S. The lines over certain vowels can be included or left off, whichever you prefer; they indicate a difference in pronunciation that disappeared in later Latin.

Comment: That was awesome. Thank you for such a thorough walkthrough. I must admit, at first I was not a fan of either patrocinium or patrocinia. But, then, as I type this, patrocinium has grown on me. I'll put it out there for a focus group. I may be able to do a play on that -inium ending and give the branding a metallic theme. I think, however, that most folks will mispronounce it as patro-sin-ium. To be honest, I'm now doubting I can really pull off a Latin name for the platform. Still, I am holding out for at least one more response, hopeful that a great name pops out.